# Publishing a WCF service using visual studio 2013, cannot find service afterwards

Tags: visual-studio, wcf, web-config

I am trying to develope a silverlight page which uses a WCF service to communicate to my database (external database on a webhotel). It all works fine locally, but when I deploy the page and run it, I get the error "The remote server returned an error: NotFound".

```
<system.serviceModel>
<bindings>
  <customBinding>
    <binding name="FundFinder.Web.FundSilverlightService.customBinding0">
      <binaryMessageEncoding />
      <httpTransport />
    </binding>
  </customBinding>
</bindings>
<services>
  <service name="FundFinder.Web.FundSilverlightService">
    <endpoint address="http://subdomain.domain.com" binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="FundFinder.Web.FundSilverlightService.customBinding0"
        contract="FundFinder.Web.FundSilverlightService" />
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"
    multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
```

I am not sure if I have configured the service correctly, the above is simply that which Visual Studio gave me when I added the service to the solution.

Comment: enable tracing in order to get a much more detailed error message, see this link http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/420538/Simple-Steps-to-Enable-Tracing-in-WCF

Answer (score 0):

This is a generic error. Please turn on debug in web.config and turn the exception details

```
  <behaviors> 
      <serviceBehaviors> 
        <behavior name=""> 
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" /> 
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" /> 
          </behavior> 
      </serviceBehaviors> ## Heading ##
    </behaviors>
```

see what exception its throwing.